# how to get current date with hundredth in Java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I want to get the time format like this pattern,
HH-MM-SS-CC, the last CC represent a hundredth of the time.
how can I get it in Java

Comment: You can add a 0 and read it as millisecond. You could can parse the centi-seconds yourself.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Wow, that really is a word: [centisecond](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is hh-mm-ss-SS (for 12 hour clock, for a 24 hour clock use 'HH').  Lowercase 's' gives you seconds, and capital 'S' gives you fractions of a second.  If you want hundredths then you'll need 'SS' to 0-999 and then cut off the final character.

From [Java DateTimeFormatter docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
------  -------                     ------------      -------
  h       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)  number            12
  H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
  m       minute-of-hour              number            30
  s       second-of-minute            number            55
  S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
  A       milli-of-day                number            1234
  n       nano-of-second              number            987654321
  N       nano-of-day                 number            1234000000
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but how can i get SS in this range 0-99

Comment: SS should give you hundredths precision (0-99), SSS would give you millisecond precision.  What are you seeing it come in as if not 0-99?

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect the need to cut off the final character to get from milliseconds to centiseconds.

Answer (score -2):

Use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`

```
Date dNow = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss:SS");
```

Comment: No, SS is for milliseconds, not fraction of seconds. It will print 2 characters only if the number of millis is less than 100.